# Possible to find out what's using javaw.exe to connect outside the network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, java, firewall

Is there any way to find out who/what is running something through java/javaw.exe, in order to determine if the outbound network connection is safe or rogue?

I use a third-party firewall (Windows Firewall Control) that interfaces with Windows 7's native firewall, and alerts me on any/all outbound connections (that don't already have a rule).

An issue, however, is javaw.exe -- because it's essentially a "gateway" program, it's not safe to allow it anytime/everytime/anyhow through the firewall.

So I'm wondering -- given no direct action or apparent cause-and-effect paired with an outbound network connection alert through javaw.exe, is there a way to determine what's doing the calling?

I'm also curious about this with svchost.exe, too.

Comment: You can check the command line parameters, if you haven't already. Open the Task Manager and select the **Process** tab. Then click **View > Select Columns** and enable the **Command Line** option. As for `svchost.exe`, it's a generic host process name for system services. If you right-click it and choose **Go to Service(s)**, all related services will be highlighted.

Comment: @and31415 Ah, great idea! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @and31415 If you put that as an answer, I'll select it as best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Command-line arguments

> A **command-line argument** or [parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter#Computing) is an item of information provided to a program when it is started. A program can have many command-line arguments that identify sources or destinations of information, or that alter the operation of the program.
>
> When a command processor is active a program is typically invoked by typing its name followed by command-line arguments (if any).
>
> <sub>Source: [Command-line interface - Arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments)</sub>

By checking the full command-line string you can shed more light on the matter.

1. [Open the Task Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-task-manager).
2. Select the **Processes** tab, then click **View > Select Columns**.
3. Enable the **Command Line** option, and click **OK** to apply the changes.

### Further reading

- [How to use the Windows Task Manager](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-windows-task-manager/)
- [What do the Task Manager memory columns mean?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-task-manager-memory-columns-mean#1TC=windows-7)

---

## svchost.exe

The executable file is described as **Host process for Windows Services**. It's a generic process that hosts different system services.

> There can be multiple instances of `svchost.exe` running on your computer, with each instance containing different services. One instance of `svchost.exe` might host a single service for a program, and another instance might host several services related to Windows. You can use Task Manager to view which services are running under each instance of `svchost.exe`.
>
> 1. Open Task Manager by right-clicking the taskbar, and then clicking **Start Task Manager**.
> 2. Click the **Processes** tab.
> 3. Click **Show processes from all users**. If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> 4. Right-click an instance of `svchost.exe`, and then click **Go to Service(s)**. The services associated with the process are highlighted on the **Services** tab.
>
> <sub>Source: [What is svchost.exe?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-svchost-exe#1TC=windows-7)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I had a "rogue" javaw process that had no command line options attached to it.

By looking into the *View > Select Columns* options I found the option:

- Image Path Name

That allowed me to see it was a jvm attached to another software package.

[image]